# Redirect IP to hostname

Tags: windows

I have a Windows XP computer running an application that connects to a database with a hardcoded IP address. Recently, the server's IP address changed and broke the program.

The source code for the app is unavailable. Is it possible to redirect an IP address to a hostname? E.g. if the server tries to access the database by looking at the old server IP, have it redirected to the name of the server instead.

Comment: Don't use the application. Hardcoding things like that is not particularly useful, you may end up finding other errors. Please contact the author to fix it or use another application.

Comment: Unfortunately the app is required and the source code lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your admin to either restore the server's IP address, which should be fixed anyway, or have him/her add the original IP to that server.

Comment: Adding the IP to the server worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A DNAT (Destination Network Address Translation) solution can do what you need.  This can be done by any system (host or router) the traffic passes through on the way to the target system.  Typically NAT is done by routers, but the capability is built into some operating systems such as Linux.  I am not awara of any DNAT capabilities in Windows XP.

NAT using names is normally not done as it fails if DNS is not available when the tables are being created.

It may be possible to multi-home the server with the old address.  This works best if the existing routing to the server supports both addresses.

Some things I would check include:

- Check for registry entries containing the IP address that appears hard coded.
- Search the executable for the IP address.  If the length of the new address is not longer than the old address it may be possible to patch the program.
- Search for configuration files containing the Old IP address.
- Search the executable for the binary IP address in native byte order or network byte order.  It might be possible to patch the program.

Before making changes make sure you have backups of the item you are changing.  This will allow you to back out the change if it fails.